How do I disconnect this while still being able to reattach it later?
I need to disconnect this piece of hardware on my window to straighten it out (it’s bent). I’m not sure how to handle this connector such that it can be disconnected and then reattached later. Can someone give me an idea? Thanks.

strong text


If you're talking about the section that looks bent where there's a phillips head screw in the slot, I'd be thinking about straightening in place rather than removing (and I wouldn't be sanguine about the repair lasting).  Might be better to get a replacement.

That’s a rivet, so disconnecting isn’t really a good option.
Remove the screws from the crank mechanism and pull the whole affair toward the interior. Then maybe you can straighten it out or, worst case, show it to a specialty window retailer for replacement.

Depending on clearances, It might be possible to grind the rivet heads off and replace with bolts and lock nuts.
